# How do we know if claims are nontrivial

Tags: us8768252

If I look at claim 4, is this not trivial?
In my middle school days, I build a wireless FM transmitter transmitting stereo audio, and I had two receivers connecting to two different speakers… but using only one of stereo channel in each of those ….. I just do not understand what is trivial and what is not in a patent. A person familiar with technology should find this concept trivial.

EDITED

> Claim 1. A wireless audio system configured to receive audio information wirelessly transmitted by an audio source, comprising:
>
> a first wireless transceiver, that is configured to establish a bidirectional secondary wireless link with the audio source for receiving and acknowledging receipt of the audio information;
>
> a second wireless transceiver, wherein said first and second wireless transceivers are configured to communicate with each other via a primary wireless link; and
>   wherein said first wireless transceiver is configured to communicate at least one communication parameter to said second wireless transceiver via said primary wireless link, wherein the communication parameter is to enable said second wireless transceiver to establish unidirectional wireless communication with said audio source in order to receive the audio information transmitted by said audio source via said secondary wireless link.

Answer (score 1):

Dependent claims like claim 4 that reference a previous claim inherit all of the limitations of the referenced chain of claims. In this case it is just to independent claim 1. That means that by definition claim 4 is narrower than claim 1. If claim 4 is seen as too broad, claim 1 is broader.

Claim 1 requires the first receiver to have a *bidirectional* link with the audio source and the first receiver to also communicate over a *different wireless link* with a second receiver. Over that channel the *first receiver tells the second receiver* how to get a unidirectional broadcast of the audio from the audio source.

I have no idea if this was novel and non obvious on the day in 2010 when its priority document was filed. Luckily the patent system is open. Anyone can go the the USPTO Public PAIR web portal and look up the entire history of the paperwork back and forth between Apple and the patent office. That lets the public see what the examiner came up as the closest reference and how the applicant argued or amended or both to get around it. To really get to the bottom of your question you could do that research for this patent.

Comment: I didn't realize it was Apple's, seems like they bought over this one. I kind of understand the breadth issue now. I was curious where the USPTO draws the line between obvious and non-obvious. In a wireless system, certain things like remote setup seems obvious to me, since without it the system will just not function. What is the difference between novelty and necessity and how do they make sure they don't simply confuse the two. Is necesscity patentable and can something be novel and necessary at the same time? Thanks for responding.

Comment: To help objective examination patent examiners can't just say "Seems obvious". The novelty test is, does any single embodiment in a single document have all of the limitation of the claim? To reject a claim for lack of novelty they need to find everything specified in that claim in one place. It is not comparing "the invention" to the past it is comparing the claims, one at a time, to the past. An obviousness rejection requires multiple references that are topic related to collectively have all of the claimed features and the examiner to declare why someone would but them together.

Comment: Sometimes the implementation is easy but seeing a problem that would benefit from that solution is hard.